# seed random numbers in c

Tags: c, random, random-seed

I am currently trying to teach myself c programming.  I am stuck on learning random numbers.  Many of the websites I visit use the time() function as a method of seeding the random number generator.  But many posts and websites I have read say that using the system clock as a method of producing random numbers is flawed.  My question is "what exactly should I be using to generate truly random numbers?  Should I just manipulate the numbers with arithmetic or is there something else?  To be specific, I'm looking for the "best practices" that programmers follow to generate random numbers in the c programming language.

Here is an example of a website I am talking about:

http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1042005782&id=1043284385

Comment: If you have to use `rand()`, then double check this link to be aware of its harm. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: if you just learning c, `srand(time(NULL))` is good enough. unless you need to invoke your program very often

Comment: I am a beginner in C, but I have programmed before.  When I learn a language I prefer to take it slow and learn the best practices.

Comment: @CroCo 30 minute video?

Comment: Some microcontrollers, such as the STM32F2 series, have a RNG peripheral. According to a data sheet: `The True random number generator peripheral implemented on STM32 F2 series is the
same as the one implemented on F4 series, and it is based on an analog circuit. This circuit
generates a continuous analog noise that feed a Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) in
order to produce a 32-bit random number.`

Comment: @FiddlingBits, well, the guy said "to generate `truly` random numbers" and since he tagged c, then the possibility he's gonna use `rand()` is high.

Comment: @CroCo Is it really worth watching... or should I just take your word for it. :-D

Comment: @FiddlingBits: The video describes almost everything wrong with `rand()`, although it doesn't mention the surprisingly frequent error of calling `srand()` for every random number, but the solution it provides, while totally correct, is C++ specific, so it won't help too much for a C project. So if you're writing in C, watch the first half, and then grab the Mersenne twister reference implementation and seed it once from `/dev/random` on any system which has that, or the Windows equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`srand(time(NULL))` is good enough for general basic use.  Its shortcomings are:

- It's not suitable for cryptography, since it's possible for an attacker to predict the pseudo-random sequence.  Random numbers used in cryptography need to be really unpredictable.
- If you run the program several times in quick succession, the RNG will be seeded with the same or similar values (since the current time hasn't changed much), so you're likely to get similar pseudo-random sequences each time.
- If you generate very many random numbers with `rand`, you're likely to find that they're not well-distributed statistically.  This can be important if you're doing something like [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) simulations.

There are more sophisticated RNG libraries available for cryptographic and statistical use.

Answer (score -2):

In case if you want a random number, use:

```
randomize () ; 

m = random(your limit); 
printf("%d", m);// dont forget to include stdlib
```

Comment: Does not `randomize()` just assigns current time to the seed? (what OP tried to avoid)

Comment: Write the include in your code snippet if you want your reader to not forget it.
Which library specifically is necessary to get the functions `random` and `randomize`?