# Always the same output with rand() with different ide envirionment too

Tags: c

why does it always give the same output even tho i run it again or run it on a different ide

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int numbers[100];
void rastnumaraekle(int insert){
    numbers[insert]=rand()%1000;
}

int main(void){
    rastnumaraekle(0);
    rastnumaraekle(1);
    rastnumaraekle(2);
    printf("%d\n",numbers[0]);
    printf("%d\n",numbers[1]);
    printf("%d\n",numbers[2]);
}
```

Comment: You need to seed `rand()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234776/seed-random-numbers-in-c.

Comment: You get the same numbers because you'll be using the same unseeded sequence. Either because you're using the same compiler or different implementations have chosen the same generator. NB: For unit testing it's recommended you do use he same seeds. Typically running the same test with different known seeds.